# Efficiently instert tuple into container through move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, emplace

I'm a `move` semantics beginner. Is this code:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(const Args & ... args){
    map<tuple<Args...>, int> cache;
    auto result = cache.emplace(move(make_tuple(args ...)),1);
    //...
    }
```

More efficient than:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(const Args & ... args){
    map<tuple<Args...>, int> cache;
    tuple<Args...> t(args...);
    auto result = cache.insert(make_pair(t,1));
    //...
    }
```

Especially if `args` contains some big object?

Same question but with `std::vector` (so no need for `make_pair` or `make_tuple`)

Comment: BTW tuple<Args...> with big object as map key is not an optimal option IMO

Comment: Can you propose one then? :)

Comment: how should I propose since I do not know what is your problem at all.

Comment: You're obviously right: this is part of a memoizator, where the `args` is the input (and for simplicity I didn't use the value type which is the return type of the memoized function)

Comment: ok first possible improvement is using `unordered_map` since key order is irrelevant

Comment: This one will definitely benefit from C++14 hetergeneous lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is for memoization, neither option is a good idea.

For unique-key containers, `emplace` and `insert` (except when `insert` is passed a `value_type` - that is, `pair<const Key, Value>`) may unconditionally allocate memory and construct the key-value pair first, and then destroy the pair and deallocate the memory if the key already exists; this is obviously costly if your key already exists. (They need to do this because in the general case you have to construct the key before you can check if it exists, and the key must be constructed directly at its final location.)

However, you also want to avoid unnecessarily copying the key, so inserting a `value_type` is no good - the `Key` in there is const-qualified and so can't be moved from.

Finally, you'd also want to avoid extra lookups. Not as costly as a memory allocation, but still good to save it.

Thus, we need to lookup the key first, and only call `emplace` if the key is not in the map. In C++11, only homogeneous lookup is allowed, so you have to make one copy of `args...`.

```
map<tuple<Args...>, int> cache;
auto key = std::make_tuple(args...);
auto it = cache.lower_bound(key); // *it is the first element whose key is
                                  // not less than 'key'
if(it != cache.end() && it->first == key) {
    // key already in the map, do what you have to do
}
else {
    // add new entry, using 'it' as hint and moving 'key' into container.
    cache.emplace_hint(it, std::move(key), /* value */);
}
```

In C++14, you can do heterogeneous lookup, which means that you can save the copy for when you actually need it:

```
map<tuple<Args...>, int, less<>> cache; // "diamond functor" enables hetergeneous lookup
auto key = std::tie(args...); // this is a tuple<const Args&...> - a tuple of references!
auto it = cache.lower_bound(key); // *it is the first element whose key is
                                  // not less than 'key'
if(it != cache.end() && it->first == key) {
    // key already in the map, do what you have to do
}
else {
    // add new entry, copying args...
    cache.emplace_hint(it, key, /* value */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really appreciated. First question: I used const for args since it's good habit when managing lvalue references. So what could change if we remove it (since your comment "the Key in there is const-qualified and so can't be moved from."). Second question: preserving the key order guranteed by map is not necessary, so unordered_map is probably preferred. But it would be better even more performant google::dense_hash_map , so the question is: heterogeneous lookup are possible with this structure or any 3rd party hash structures?

Comment: @justHelloWorld 1) The issue is the const-qualification in the `map`'s `value_type` (`pair<const Key, value>`), not on `args`; there's nothing you can do about it. 2) unordered_map doesn't support heterogeneous lookup; I don't know about third-party hash structures - you'll have to check their documentation.

Comment: I think that your code doesn't work since you are comparing a `tuple<const Args&...>` (so `key`) and `tuple<const Args ...`>` (so `it->first`), but please answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997854/no-defined-for-boosttuples?noredirect=1#comment61549377_36997854) question that I opened on this problem.

Comment: @justHelloWorld `std::tuple` handles heterogeneous comparisons just fine. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: Please, answer/comment on the other question. Btw, as you can see I almost did copy and paste of your code and I found a solution which works without using `std::tie`, so I think the problem is not elsewhere :D

Comment: @justHelloWorld I'm not a big fan of somebody mutilating my code, breaking it, and then claiming that the error is in my code.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the difference between the codes in the `std::tie` section, I apologize.\

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(const Args & ... args){
    map<tuple<Args...>, int> cache;
    auto result = cache.emplace(move(make_tuple(args ...)),1);
    //...
}
```

This code should be faster. `emplace` perform in-place constructing (perfect forwarding). This should guarantee a minimum number of constructing and copies. However, it would not harm if you benchmark them.

In general, use emplace when possible. It should be always a better option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that I'm finally starting to understanding the `move` tricks :)

Comment: BTW in-place constructing is because of the emplace not because of the move

Comment: but then the `move(...)` is useless?

Comment: @justHelloWorld to be honest with you.. I do not know. I am not sure perfect forwarding will take maketuple and excute it in-place. if so then move is useless other wise it is important. You may not accept the answer since someone with better knowledge give you a better answer

Comment: I appreciate your honesty :)

Comment: "In general, use emplace when possible. It should be always a better option." No, not necessarily for unique-key containers.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
auto result = cache.emplace(move(make_tuple(args ...)),1);
```

vs

```
auto result = cache.emplace(make_tuple(args ...),1);
```

does not make a difference. `make_tuple(args...)` is a temporary and therefor passed on as rvalue reference. The move does not add anything.

Something different would be

```
tuple<Args...> t(args...);
auto result = cache.emplace(t, 1);
```

Now `emplace()` receives an lvalue reference thus using the copy constructor of std::pair instead of the move constructor.

In any case, if large data is in any of the `args...` your problem lies somewhere else anyhow. All the `args` are currently passed on as lvalue references.

What you would want to do is:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args && ... args){
    map<tuple<Args...>, int> cache;
    auto result = cache.emplace(make_tuple(forward<Args>(args)...)),1);
    //...
}
```

If you pass an rvalue reference to `foo()`, then `forward<Args>(args)...` forwards it as rvalue reference thus resulting in a move instead of a copy. If you call `foo()` with an lvalue reference, it will be forwarded as lvalue.

Comment: At the very least, drop that `const`.

Comment: @T.C. Was a copy/paste oversight, thanks. But what do you mean by 'at the very least'?