# no == defined for boost::tuples

Tags: c++, equals-operator, boost-tuples

I have this code:

```
...
#include "boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp"
...
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
function<ReturnType(Args...)> memoize(const Args && ... args)
{
    using noRef = boost::tuple<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...>;
    static map<noRef, ReturnType, less<>> cache;
    auto key = std::tie(noRef{ boost::make_tuple(args ...) });
    auto it = cache.lower_bound(key);
    ReturnType result;
    if (it->first == key) { ...
```

But when I try to compile it I receive this error:

```
error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const noRef' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Why this happens, since `noRef` is an alias for `boost::tuple` and `tuple_comparison` should manage this case?

**ERROR FOUND, DON'T KNOW HOW TO SOLVE IT:**

It seems that the error was in the `std::tie` operation. So rewriting it as:

```
    auto key = noRef{ boost::make_tuple(args ...) };
```

Works fine. The problem is that this solution is inefficient, since `key` is a potentially expensive copy of the whole tuple, while using `tie` is a tuple of references (much smaller). So, how can I take a reference to `it->first` tuple? Should I use the same `tie` trick?

Comment: What are the types you instantiate this with? `operator==` for tuples only works if all of the element types support `operator==`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here : `std::tie(noRef{ boost::make_tuple(args ...) });`?. Also, if you can use `std::tie`, then why not use `std::tuple` as well?

Comment: Also, what does `const` do in `const Args &&`?

Comment: Edited just a second before of @Nawaz 's answer :D Look at the new section

Comment: i don't think that the `const` is relevant for this question, just from copy and paste of the whole code :)

Comment: `std::tie(noRef{ boost::make_tuple(args ...) })` this makes zero sense. If you insist on using `boost::tuple`, then that should just be `boost::tie(args...)`. None of the `noRef` or `make_tuple` nonsense.

Comment: This absolutely make 100% sense for the applications that I'm implementing, since I don't want to store lvalue references values inside the `boost::tuple` that I'm creating (I have to save it and read it later on a file).

Comment: What I mean is that maybe you are right saying that instruction doesn't make sense, but `boost:tie(args...)` is not feasible for the application

Comment: The map stores tuple of values; the tuple of references should *only* be used for lookup. If you are using it elsewhere, well, that's your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to be rude, but the posted error persists even using `auto key = std::tie(args ...);` and then `if( it->first == key)`

Comment: In particular `error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'std::tuple<vecD &>' to 'const noRef'` is posted below

Comment: If you use `boost::tuple`s, then use `boost::tie`. If you use `std::tuple`s, then use `std::tie`. They are not designed to interop. /sigh

Comment: You're right. If you post this solution as an answer I'm gonna chose it. One last note: is correct that we should use `if(it!=cache.end() && it->first == key)` instead of `if(it->first==key)` and all the rest the same, right?

Comment: @justHelloWorld Right - you spotted an actual bug in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Np, thanks for your answer (waiting that you officially post it ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason this line compiles at all is MSVC's Evil Extension<sup>TM</sup> which allows non-const lvalue references to bind to temporaries:

```
auto key = std::tie(noRef{ boost::make_tuple(args ...) });
```

This should simply be

```
auto key = boost::tie(args...);
```

which creates a `boost::tuple` of references to be used for lookup later.

Also, as noted in the comments, the `if` check should verify `it != cache.end()` first before attempting to dereference it (thanks!).

Finally, `const Args && ...` doesn't make much sense, as one is unlikely to want to accept const rvalues. It probably should be either `const Args&...` or `Args&&...`.